# How to update a manyToMany collection of an entity in onFlush event listener?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this entity:

```
<?php

namespace Comakai\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM,
    Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Stuff {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Apple", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $apples;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Pig")
     */
    private $pigs;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->apples = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->pigs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setApples($apples) {

        $this->getApples()->clear();

        foreach ($apples as $apple) {

            $this->addApple($apple);
        }
    }

    public function setPigs($pigs) {

        $this->getPigs()->clear();

        foreach ($pigs as $pig) {

            $this->addPig($pig);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param text $content
     */
    public function setContent($content) {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return text 
     */
    public function getContent() {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Add apples
     *
     * @param Comakai\MyBundle\Entity\Apple $apples
     */
    public function addApple(\Comakai\MyBundle\Entity\Apple $apples) {
        $this->apples[] = $apples;
    }

    /**
     * Get apples
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getApples() {
        return $this->apples;
    }


    /**
    * Add pigs
    *
    * @param Comakai\MyBundle\Entity\Pig $pigs
    */
    public function addPig(\Comakai\MyBundle\Entity\Pig $pigs) {
        $this->pigs[] = $pigs;
    }

    /**
    * Get pigs
    *
    * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
    */
    public function getPigs() {
        return $this->pigs;
    }
}
```

and this listener:

```
<?php

namespace Comakai\MyBundle\Listener;

use Comakai\MyBundle\Util\SluggerParser
    Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs,
    Comakai\MyBundle\Entity\Stuff,
    Comakai\MyBundle\Entity\Apple,
    Comakai\MyBundle\Entity\Pig;

class Listener {

    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs $ea
     */
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $ea) {

        $em = $ea->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() AS $entity) {

            $this->save($entity, $em, $uow);

        }

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() AS $entity) {

            $this->save($entity, $em, $uow);

        }
    }

    public function save($entity, $em, $uow) {

        if ($entity instanceof Stuff) {

            $pigRepository = $em->getRepository('Comakai\MyBundle\Entity\Pig');
            $content = $entity->getContent();

            preg_match_all('/@@ pig:(\d+) @@/i', $content, $matches);
            $entity->getPigs()->clear();

            foreach($matches[1] as $pigID) {

                $pig = $pigRepository->find($pigID);

                if(!empty($pig)) {

                    $entity->addPig($pig);

                }

            }

            $entity->setContent($content);

            $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);
            $uow->computeChangeSet($meta, $entity);

        }
    }

}
```

And it works fine if apple's collection is empty, but if it has some item I get a duplication error.

How can I tell to the UnitOfWork that I only want to recalculate the pig's collection?

**UPDATE**

There is a new preFlush event (https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/169) and I think this kind of things can be done there. That PR is not in the branch I'm using but let's try it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When updating an entity during a listener's *onFlush* event, all you need to call is `computeChangeSet()`:

```
// make changes to entity
$entity->field = 'value';

// or assign an existing entity to an assocation
$entity->user = $myExistingUserEntity;
$entity->tags->add($myExistingTagEntity);

$meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
$uow->computeChangeSet($meta, $entity);
```

If you're creating other entities too, you need to persist them and compute their changes first!

```
$myNewUserEntity = new Entity\User;
$myNewTagEntity = new Entity\Tag;

$entity->user = $myNewUserEntity;
// make sure you call add() on the owning side for *ToMany associations
$entity->tags->add($myNewTagEntity);

$em->persist($myNewUserEntity);
$em->persist($myNewTagEntity);

$metaUser = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($myNewUserEntity));
$uow->computeChangeSet($metaUser, $myNewUserEntity);

$metaTag = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($myNewTagEntity));
$uow->computeChangeSet($metaTag, $myNewTagEntity);

$meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
$uow->computeChangeSet($meta, $entity);
```

Comment: Sorry but the preFlush solved my problem. Modifying the UoW is kind of hacking and very messy, it can drive you crazy with collections.

Comment: Coma, I agree. You're question was about doing stuff in onFlush() though, and imho this is the only way to do it. If your use case can be implemented in preFlush() instead, that's great!

Comment: Well... it seems that the so waited preFlush event does almost anything... all the scheduled lists are empty.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but glad my solution helped in the end. Btw, I think you meant "does almost _nothing_" ;)

Comment: You are my hero @dotjon!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the new preFlush event (Symfony 2.1).

Add a listener to the event (is a bad practice to inject the whole service container but [sometimes is the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708822/circular-reference-when-injecting-security-context-into-entity-listener-class)):

```
services:
    mybundle.updater.listener:
        class: Foo\MyBundle\Listener\UpdaterListener
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preFlush }
```

And the listener should be something like:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\MyBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreFlushEventArgs;
use Foo\MyBundle\SomeInterface;

class UpdaterListener
{
    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreFlushEventArgs $ea
     */
    public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $ea)
    {
        /* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
        $em = $ea->getEntityManager();
        /* @var $uow \Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork */
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {

            if($entity instanceof SomeInterface) {

               /*
                * do your stuff here and don't worry because
                * it'll execute before the flush
                */

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When wanting to update the current entity you are sending to `onFlush` and also creating an association to that entity

(for this example I will use `Parent` object and `child` object)

Let's say when I change the parent object property 'stressed' to `1` I also want to associate a brand new `child` object to the parent object in my `onflush` method, it will look something like this:

```
public function onFlush(onFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    ....

    $child = $this->createChild($em, $entity); // return the new object. just the object.
    $uow->persist($child);
    $childMeta = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor('AcmeFamilyTreeBundle:Child');
    $uow->computeChangeSet($childMeta, $child)

    $parent->setStressed(1);
    $parentMeta = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor('AcmeFamilyTreeBundle:Parent');
    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($parentMeta, $parent)
}
```

So there you see:

1. you need to persist your child object using `$uow->persist()` **not** `$em->persist()`
2. `computeChangeSet` on the child object.
3. `recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet` on the parent object

---

For help with creating the onFlush method, please see [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush)