# Symfony 2: Get Security Context Outside of Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to write an event listener that needs access to the users permission level. In the controller I use the following code

**Code:**

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');

if($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER')){
    //Do Something
}
```

But outside of a controller I can't work out how to get the security context. Is it possible?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561013/injecting-securitycontext-services-into-a-listener-class-in-symfony2-causes-circ

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best way to do this is using (as phpisuber said) **dependency injection** through the [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). But, instead of injecting the entire container (which is considered bad practice as it makes your entire class less testable and breaks loose coupling) you should inject the `security.context` service like so:

```
acme_foo.bar_service:
    class: %acme_foo.bar_service.class%
    arguments:
        - @security.context
```

Your service can be something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\FooBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class BarService
{
    /**
     * @var SecurityContext
     */
    protected $context;

    /**
     * @param SecurityContext $context
     */
    public function __construct($context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        return $this->context->isGranted('ROLE_USER');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is two ways to get it outside a controller:

**Dependency Injection:**

This is the correct way to do it, all you need is in the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

```
mybundle.model.mymodel:
class: %mybundle.model.myclass%
arguments: [@servicecontainer]
```

**Quick and Dirty:**

```
global $kernel;
$securityContext = $kernel->getContainer()->get('security.context');
```

Comment: Please don't use the quick and dirty solution! You should never use a global!

Comment: This solution completely breaks the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: @Touki Care to explain more? Im genuinely interested. RamonKleiss is correct the Q&D solution is not a good idea to use, but I include it for those who want to make a quick concept check before spending the 20 minutes of facedesking through symfony configuration to inject the container into a model. Test your code, then go back and inject the container properly. Mmmhm.

Comment: @phpisuber01 This is the *Principle of Least Knowledge*. When you inject the whole service container as a dependency, your object lies on what it really needs. Your unit becomes hard to test without building the whole container. [This Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) may help you understand  this principle

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little dated, but it still came up as one of the first results on Google.

The answers in this post reference the `SecurityContext` class, which is no longer supported as of Symfony 2.6. The accepted answer for this post is misleading because of the class deprecation.

Try this code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578674/3321344):

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use YourNameSpace\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class LoginController extends Controller{

    public function registerAction()
    {    
        $user = //Handle getting or creating the user entity likely with a posted form
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
        $this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
    }
}
```