# Symfony2 - Inject the currently logged in user into a listener

Tags: symfony, event-listener, security-context-token

I am trying to inject the currently logged in user into a Listener. My goal is to write a current \DateTime() to the 'last_active' column of my 'demo_user' table every time the user does any action (both of this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7562976/2624140) methods do not work for me) .

*app/config/config.yml*

```
# ...
services:
    demo.listener:
        class: Demo\UserBundle\EventListener\ActivityWatcher.php
        arguments: ['@service_container']
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

*src/Demo/UserBundle/EventListener/ActivityWatcher.php*

```
namespace Demo\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Demo\UserBundle\Entity\DemoUser;

class ActivityWatcher
{

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {   
        $this->container = $container;
    }


    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if ($entity instanceof DemoUser) {
            $token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();
            $user = $token->getUser();

            if($entity->getId() == $user->getId()) {
                $entity->setLastActivity( new \DateTime() );
                $entityManager->persist($entity);
                $entityManager->flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the $token is always empty...
UPDATE: Didn't mention, that I'm logged in and authenticated when this happens

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getUser()
on a non-object ...
```

Any ideas? Arrgh, thanks, Jan

UPDATE:

I also tried only to inject the security.context:

```
arguments: ["@security.context"]
```

but got a

```
ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", path: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> wwk.listener -> security.context -> security.authentication.manager -> security.user.provider.concrete.administrators".
```

Comment: Not an ellegant solution but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561013/injecting-securitycontext-services-into-a-listener-class-in-symfony2-causes-circ

Comment: I think I'm exactly trying to do this at the moment, but without any success

Comment: The link provided by @JovanPerovic is fine. The correct answer is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561013/injecting-securitycontext-into-a-listener-prepersist-or-preupdate-in-symfony2-to#26011863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `symfony 2.4` you should be able to inject expression, 
so instead of  `@service_container`
use
`@=service('security.context').getToken().getUser()` to get user directly

Comment: Hi, I tryed this but I have the same problem : *Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"*. It looks like calling `@security.context` while using a `doctrine.event_listener̀` still raise the error.

Comment: this worked perfectly for me. Thank you Symfony genie

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the circular reference problem when injecting the current user is implementing a user callable.

You can use the [UserCallable](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/src/Knp/DoctrineBehaviors/ORM/Blameable/UserCallable.php) class provided by KnpDoctrineBehaviors.

At first you need to create a service from the user callable class and inject the container into it.

You can find a YML example on how to do this in the config provided by [KnpDoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/config/orm-services.yml#L66).

Now inject your UserCallable service into your listener and retrieve the user from the user-callable as you can see in the [source of Blameable listener](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/src/Knp/DoctrineBehaviors/ORM/Blameable/BlameableListener.php#L274).