# One to one relationship on two tables sharing primary key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want two tables, `Person` and `Address`, to share their primary key:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Person (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Address (personId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

I'm trying to model the idea that when you create a `Person`, you're also creating an `Address` for it.

I came up with the following mapping:

```php
class Person
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"all"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="personId")
     */
    private $address;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->address = new Address($this);
    }
}

class Address
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Person")
     * @JoinColumn(name="personId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $person;

    public function __construct(Person $person) {
        $this->person = $person;
    }
}
```

When I try to persist `Person`, I would expect it to cascade to `Address`, but I get the following exception:

**Doctrine\ORM\ORMException**

> Entity of type `Address` has identity through a foreign entity `Person`,
>   however this entity has no identity itself. You have to call
>   `EntityManager#persist()` on the related entity and make sure that an
>   identifier was generated before trying to persist `Address`.
>   In case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL `Auto-Increment`
>   or PostgreSQL `SERIAL`) this means you have to call `EntityManager#flush()`
>   between both persist operations.

I can't explicitly call `flush()`, because I'm not explicitly `persist()`ing `Address`, instead I'm expecting `Person` to cascade persist `Address`.

So as far as I understand it, it should be Doctrine's job to `flush()` at the right moment to get the `id`.

This one-to-one relationship cascades fine when using different `auto_increment` ids for both `Person` and `Address` (but then I have to add an `addressId` to `Person`).

My aim is to make them share the same `id`.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you come up with a solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Nico not yet! I've given up for now and use an extra field.

Answer (score 3):

How about use [Identity through foreign Entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities) in doctrine 2.1?

In your scenario you can use `@ManyToOne` instead `@OneToOne` association.

#### Edit

The association is persisted when you persist the owning side. In your mapping, that is the `Address`. Change your mapping so the owner has the foreign key and everything should work fine.

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"all"}, inversedBy="person")
 * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="personId")
 */
private $address;
```

In other words, if `Address` should be owner by the `Person` then you must persist `Address` at first place to in order to persist the association.
If you want the association to be persisted with `Person`, then you should mark the `Person` to be the owning side and `Address` to be the **inverse** side:

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="address")
 * @JoinColumn(name="personId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $person;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using. And my association is definitely a one-to-one, no doubt about that, and is supported as well: "*Only allowed on Many-To-One or One-To-One associations.*".

Comment: What is exactly your Doctrine version?

Comment: The latest version: 2.4.0

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [symfony listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561013/injecting-securitycontext-into-a-listener-prepersist-or-preupdate-in-symfony2-to) and remove the auto increment strategy from adress entity :

First create a Listner and crete your listner class like AdressGenerator.php

```
<?php

namespace Zodiac\HelperBundle\Listener;


use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AAA\XXXBundle\Entity\Person;
use AAA\XXXBundle\Entity\Adress;

class AdressGenerator
{
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // This function is called just beforethe event Persist 
        // The AdressGeneratorlistner is defined in the config.yml file
        // Get the entity manager and the entity from le LifecycleEventArgs
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $entity = $args->getEntity();


        if ($entity instanceof Person) {
            //Create the Adress entity
            $adress = new Adress();
            $adress->setId($entity->getId()); 
            $em->persist($adress);
            $entity->setAdress($adress);
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

        }

    }
}
```

Then add your listener service in the config.yml:

```
services:
AdressGenerator.listener:
    class: AAA\xxxBundle\Listener\AdressGenerator
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

Comment: On prePersist, the $entity has no id yet the first time. But the idea is nice, at least to order the code, will read the doc.

Comment: Then i think postPersist should do the job. You can get the entity Id and persist your entities.

Comment: I shaked your solution with mine to finally end up with something that work very well with a simple `persist()`. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I don't know if that's the best (it looks heavy to me).

That's not a mapping problem, but the way we persist :

Instead of doing:

```
$em->persist($person);
$em->flush();
```

We should do:

```
$em->transactional(function($em) use ($person)
{
    $address = $person->getAddress();
    $person->setAddress(null);
    $em->persist($person);
    $em->flush();
    $address->setPerson($person);
    $em->persist($address);
    $em->flush();
});
```

If somebody has a cleaner solution, (s)he'll get the bounty :-).