# Doctrine 2.5. OneToOne relationship sharing primary key

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, one-to-one

In my app, when users sign up I have to send them an email with a validation key, as usually happens on most websites, I'm trying to do this with Doctrine but I can’t get it to work when I try to `persist()` the user.

First of all, I think the correct way in this case is to use a OneToOne unidirectional relationship, but I don’t know if it would be better to use a bidirectional one. I've tried both and I always get an error.

I have read these two questions carefully:

[One to one relationship on two tables sharing primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708898/one-to-one-relationship-on-two-tables-sharing-primary-key)

[Doctrine one-to-one unidirectional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654996/doctrine-one-to-one-unidirectional)

As well as [this part of the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html). When I validate the schema (`php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`) everything is fine.

```
class Usuario {
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
  private $id;

  // ...
}

class ClaveVal {
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Usuario")
   */
  private $usuario;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="clave", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
   * @Assert\NotBlank()
   */
  private $clave;

  // ...
}
```

Which is quite similar to [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity).

Now, I'm trying to `persist()` a new Usuario and a new ClaveVal for this usuario like this:

```
$usuario = new Usuario();
// Add usuario attributes
$claveVal = new ClaveVal();
$claveVal->setUsuario($usuario);
$claveVal->setClave(‘123456’);
$em->persist($usuario);
$em->persist($claveVal);
```

But I get this error:

> The given entity of type 'AppBundle\Entity\ClaveVal'
>   (AppBundle\Entity\ClaveVal@000000007020f28f0000000031d5c8c6) has no
>   identity/no id values set. It cannot be added to the identity map

I know why this happens. This works perfectly:

```
  $em->persist($usuario);
  $em->flush();
  $em->persist($claveVal);
  $em->flush();
```

But I don't want to do that because I want it to be a `unit of work` using `flush()` only once.

Besides, as the author of the post I linked above says, it should be Doctrine's job to `flush()` at the right moment to get the id.

So, how can I achieve this using `flush()` only once (and without using transactions or listeners, I'm sure there is an easier way to do this)? Would it be better to use a bidirectional OneToOne relationship? As I said, I tried it too but I got the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: might look into the doctrine cascade functionality: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: Your ClaveVal Entity should have primary key. This is for sure.

Comment: I triied with `@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Usuario", cascade={"persist", "remove"})`, but didn't work. @Artur, ClaveVal has usuario as PK and FK

Comment: You need to specify the join column on either the `Usuario` entity or the `ClaveVal` entity, otherwise Doctrine has no idea how these two entities are related.